# What is the male to female ratio for each occupation using Pandas

Tags: python

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/DAT8/master/data/u.user', sep ='|')
df.head()

df.groupby(["occupation", "gender"])["occupation"].count()
```

The output gives me the count of each F and M, but how do I calculate the ratio?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the ratio of genders in each occupation, try this -

```
df.groupby(["occupation"])["gender"].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```

Further you want them in tabular format, unstack the results as -

```
(df.groupby(["occupation"])["gender"].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100).unstack('gender', fill_value=0)
```